# Lithium PHP form helper fails while generating URL when using globalization

Tags: php, localization, globalization, lithium

I have activated globalization config in my lithium framework.

When I using html helper in my View like '$this->form->create()'.

The page threw an Exception with "No parameter match found for URL `{$url}`".

I found that in my '**Lithium\action\Request**' object ,the **Param** property has a key named '**locale**' , It detected the locale setting with "zh_CN" .That's right however case the problem.The route object could not find the right match.

So how to deal with it? Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`li3 route` command](http://lithify.me/docs/lithium/console/command/Route%3a%3aall%28%29) to help you debugging this.

Make sure you have the required routes in [your `app/config/routes.php`](https://github.com/UnionOfRAD/framework/blob/master/app/config/routes.php#L22-L33) and the languages (here `zh_CN`) in the `locales` environment variable.